# get image dimension from blob column in MySQL database

Tags: c++, mysql, image, blob

I want to read image from a database, image column is a **MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB** type and I read column using this code. Currently, Blob image converted as a **char** * array

```
    //Get the total number of fields
    int fieldCount = mysql_num_fields(result);

    //Get field information of a row of data
    MYSQL_FIELD *fields = mysql_fetch_fields(result);

    while (m_row = mysql_fetch_row(result))
    {
        for (int i = 0;i < fieldCount; ++i)
        {
            if (fields[i].type == MYSQL_TYPE_BLOB)
            {
                unsigned long length = mysql_fetch_lengths(result)[i];
                char* buffer = new char[length + 1];
                memset(buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));

                memcpy(buffer, m_row[i], length);
            }
        }   
    }
```

In order to do some tests on image, I should know the image dimension *without writing image on disk and reading it again*?

Another way to read data from Mysql database is :

```
        res = stmt->executeQuery("MY QUERY TO DATABASE");
        while (res->next())
        {
            std::istream *blobData = res->getBlob("image");
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char> isb = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(*blobData);
            std::string blobString = std::string(isb, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
            tempFR.image = blobString;
            blobData->seekg(0, ios::end);
            tempFR.imageSize = blobData->tellg();




            std::istream *blobIn;
            char buffer[tempFR.imageSize];
            memset(buffer, '\0', tempFR.imageSize);
            blobIn = res->getBlob("image");
            blobIn->read((char*)buffer, tempFR.imageSize);
        }
```

**Notice**:

**imageSize** and **length** are the overall image size, for example **1000**.

**Update#1: How image will be reconstruct meanwhile writing it to disk?**

In the first case it's possible to write the blob_image to disk via this codes:

```
        stringstream pic_name;
        pic_name << "car.jpeg";
        ofstream outfile(pic_name.str(), ios::binary);

        outfile.write(buffer, length);
```

and in the second ones:

```
    std::ofstream outfile ("car.jpeg",std::ofstream::binary);
    outfile.write (buffer, tempFR.imageSize);
    outfile.close();
```

In both cases image writed to disk correctly. But I want to find **image dimension** without **writing** it to disk and **reading** it again?

Comment: On any properly designed system (database), either the blob would contain an image in a specific self-sufficient format (you can find which by looking at code that write them to database) or would have neighbouring columns contain metadatas. Or the format is known and constant for all (sizes ratio for instance). Any other scenario results in loss of data.

Comment: @Alceste_ This table does not have any metadata column. And I know that writing `blobIn` to disk is simple. Is it possible without knowing image dimension?

Comment: it's not, unless the blob originates from a format containing metadatas.
How would you differentiate bewteen a 42x420 picture and a 420x42 picture?

Comment: @Alceste_ I added related codes to write image to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By decoding buffered image:

```
length = mysql_fetch_lengths(result)[i];
buffer = new char[length + 1];
memset(buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));
    
memcpy(buffer, m_row[i], length);
    
matImg = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(1, length, CV_8UC1, buffer), cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
```

At first, copy array to buffer, then convert it to a `cv::Mat` and finally decode it. It will be a `cv::Mat` image.